# Maintaining page scroll position after postback in listview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, updatepanel, postback

I have a `ListView` that contains details of customers. There are thousands of customer records in this `ListView`.

Whenever I select/click on a customer name, it shows the selected customer's history and all data in right side panel.

Everything is in `UpdatePanel`s, and the page does not refresh on any operation.

But, when I click on a customer name, it scrolls to the top of the page.

So, how do I maintain the scroll position for a page after an `UpdatePanel` posts back from `ListView`?

Comment: Have you looked at [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that. But problem is after selecting customer scrollbars are working weirdly...

Comment: And also there are many functionalities like modal popup, tabs, etc. Those are messing up with each other.